# jQuery if/else form validation code does not work

Tags: jquery, validation, if-statement, blur, focusout

Here is my code. I just want to get alert besides the text input area when an empty input are focused out. Could you please tell me what the wrong thing is with my code? Thanks for your help

```
<input class="required1" type="text" name="name" value="" />
<span class="alert1"></span>


<script>
$(".required1").blur(function () {
    var y = $(".required1").val;

    if (y=="") {
        $(".alert1").text("This area is required");
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val` is a method, use `()` to invoke it.

```
var y = $(".required1").val();
```

Also, you probably want to use `this` if that class is used more than once:

```
var y = this.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var y = $(".required1").val;
```

To

```
var y = $(".required1").val();
```